# DataTable in Shiny App not displaying Icons in Each Row

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Can anyone please tell me why the icons arent displaying in the rendered data table? All I can see is the code as opposed to one Trash Icon in the remove column for each of the rows in my table

It's worked fine for me on previous Shiny Apps - but when starting again for a new project I cant work out what's different.

Thanks!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)


values <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3),b = c(4,5,6))

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('TabBU')
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  shinyInput <- function(FUN, n, id, ses, ...) {
    as.character(FUN(paste0(id, n), ...))
  }
  
  getRemoveButton <- function(n, idS = "", lab = "Pit") {
    if (stringr::str_length(idS) > 0) idS <- paste0(idS, "-")
    ret <- shinyInput(actionButton, n,
                      'button_', label = "Remove",icon = icon("trash-alt"),
                      onclick = sprintf('Shiny.onInputChange(\"%sremove_button_%s\",  this.id)' ,idS, lab))
    return (ret)
  }
  
  
  
  
  values = values %>%
    mutate(id = 1:nrow(values)) 
  
  values = values %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(Remove = getRemoveButton(id, idS = "", lab = "Tab1")) 
  
  output$TabBU <- renderDT(values)
  
}





shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: To render the HTML, use `escape = FALSE` in the `renderDT` function.  This will display the buttons instead of the HTML.  Unfortunately, the buttons only show the label but not the icon, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I had the same issue and for whatever reason, placing an `actionButton` with an icon *outside* of the datatable makes the icons show up on the buttons inside the datatable. I have no idea why this works, but I used the incredibly kludgy approach of putting that button inside of a div with `display: none` set so it doesn't show:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- shinyUI({
  fluidPage(
    # comment out this top div and the icons disappear! why? who knows?!
    tags$div(
      class="container",
      style="display: none;",
      tags$div(
        style="margin-top: 50xp;",
        actionButton(
          "add_thing",
          label="do it",
          class="btn-success",
          icon=icon("plus")
        )
      )
    ),
    tags$div(
      class = "container",
      style = "margin-top: 50px;",
      DT::DTOutput("tabs",width="100%")
    )
  )
})



create_btns <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    purrr::map_chr(~
                     paste0(
                       '<div class = "btn-group">
                   <button class="btn btn-default action-button btn-info action_button" id="edit_',
                       .x, '" type="button" onclick=get_id(this.id)><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                   <button class="btn btn-default action-button btn-danger action_button" id="delete_',
                       .x, '" type="button" onclick=get_id(this.id)><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></button></div>'
                     ))
}

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session) {
  dataset <- reactive({
    mtcars %>%
      rownames_to_column("car") %>%
      mutate(buttons = create_btns(1:nrow(.)))
  })
  
  output$tabs <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      isolate(dataset()),
      escape = F,
      rownames = FALSE,
      selection="none"
    )
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: It may have something to do with how the shiny library loads the icons. The actionButton is loaded at startup whereas the buttons in the datatable are possibly loaded later... (this is sheer speculation)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Icon and the label, you can try writing the icon argument after onclick, like this:

```
ret <- shinyInput(actionButton, n,
                    'button_', label = "Remove",
                    onclick = sprintf('Shiny.onInputChange(\"%sremove_button_%s\",  this.id)' ,idS, lab),
                    style = "color: white;
                           background-color: red",
                    icon = icon("trash"))
```

And if you want just the icon you can set `label = ""`